# I have issue regarding windows updates and microsoft store updates

Tags: windows, error-handling, operating-system, updates, auto-update

Hello I have been trying to update my windows for months and the same error keeps coming up which is the following error 0x800f0905. It has affected a lot of functions in my pc such as my killer networking app and I believe it has to do with my microsoft store as well which hasnt updated any app in months. everytime i try to update something the legend "something happened on our end" pops up and I cant seem to find a solution. So I have the microsoft store issue and the windows update error 0x800f0905. Currently the update I need to get is the 23h2 update. the other ones arent apparently required anymore. still I need to solve this please help

I tried DISM cleanup, I tried manual update installation, I tried re installing microsoft store and nothing worked